# How to use 'function' in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am creating a function like this in big query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
   FN_MATRL_NUM_LAST10(IN_pMatrl_Num IN main_prod.matrl_num%TYPE) RETURN 
   VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS 
   /**********************************************************************
   * Modified By : Boris , Daniel, Steve, Jeff S., Kashyap               *
```

but i am getting an error "Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got keyword IN at [2:37]"

please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with Oracle? Or perhaps more to the point, why are you apparently trying to use Oracle syntax instead of [BigQuery syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)?

Comment: Here is the [`CREATE FUNCTION` syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement), assuming the goal is to create a persistent user-defined function.